# Many app store apps, one start screen

Tags: android, android-intent, installation

I want users to download different apps within a suite, think MS Office, but have one main screen to pick each app from. Users can add (or remove) apps by downloading them from Google, etc.

- I don't want users to have to have multiple copies of the same start screen, one in each app, if possible, because I want to minimize internal or external memory storage use.
- Alternately, If you download and instal one app from my suite, can I use that to really install two apps, the useful app and a second mainscreen app that wont be installed if you have it already installed via another of my programs from my suite? I don't want the user bothered with options or HAVE TO download 2 apps. I want to allow users to install or uninstall apps as needed.
- If I start an app from the one apps "select which app you want", how do I make the second app in my suite open, e.g. Word, without opening the second apps "select which app you want" start screen. [e.g. should I send intents between apps, or have alternate start activities in the manifest?]
- Can I install new apps, but and then delete duplicate app select menu images within the new program if another program has already installed the app select menu screen.

Suggestions and or code welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your approach is very honourable.
- Apps and apks do not have any programmatic control over what is being installed and what not during the installation process and are lacking the rights to alter their installation afterwards, so "install one or two apps" will not work as you describe it.
- You can launch the other app with a different intent or with intent extras, so avoiding the other splash screen wouldn't be a problem.

I'd say you'll have to have the splash screen code in all of your apps *unless* you publish your splash screen/dashboard as the only app of the suite and allow the user to download the suite's single functionalities as [expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html), which may or may not suit and/or complicate your licence approach.

Comment: I'll have to make the best of it then. Thanks for your help.